# Resizing screen size for selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I have the following selenium java code.

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.net.URL;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(System.getProperty("webDriverUrl")), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
    baseUrl = System.getProperty("baseUrl");
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
}

@Test
public void testScreenSize(){
    driver.manage().window().setSize(992, 768);
}
```

I still cant seem to resize my window screen. The text 'window' is seen as an error. Any idea why?

**UPDATE:**

I can now run the code. It doesnt show any error. It was because of the dependency version number. 
This is my current code in BeforeClass. My firefox browser opens but doesnt resize to the size I want. Also, I only need it to resize by width. The height is not important.

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(System.getProperty("webDriverUrl")), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
    baseUrl = System.getProperty("baseUrl");
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(992, 768));
```

Comment: Use driver.manage().window().setSize((new Dimension(intwidth, intheight)));

Comment: I tried this and it still gives an error. I get the following error: Error:(84, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method window()
  location: interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get it working. My code was right. It was just the code

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(991, 1100));
```

should have been after the driver creation.

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(System.getProperty("webDriverUrl")), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(991, 1100));
    baseUrl = System.getProperty("baseUrl");
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works absolutely fine for me without any issues on selenium-server 2.48.2 with FF41.0.2

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SO35079080 {

    static WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("WDURL"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testScreenSize(){
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(992, 768));
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dimension instead of direct use of  `driver.manage().window().setSize(992, 768);`

Follow below code, `window` has `setSize()` method,

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(992, 768);
driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension)
```

There is another way also you can set size of window,

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd one and still get an error. The following error: Error:(84, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method window()
  location: interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options

Comment: Can you tell me which type of error? if error-log then it will be easy

Comment: error-log?

I see the following error on the side: cannot resolve method 'window()'

Comment: make sure your driver was successfully created. on driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(System.getProperty("webDriverUrl")), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());

Comment: The driver was created. I have a few other @Test before this. Although they don't follow a specific order when executing, all except this run successfully.

Comment: try with and let me know
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl);

Comment: use priority for specific orders

Comment: Still get the following error Error:(85, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method window()
  location: interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options

Comment: as per @ShekharSwami to execute test on priority wise you have to set priority or use testng xml file.

Comment: Please post your imports

Comment: @ShekharSwami added it in the question now.

Comment: Looks like compilation issue or import issue, try to run below code in single method which have @Test,
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.get(baseUrl); 
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(992, 768);
driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension); and let me know. I have tested code and it worked.

Comment: Tried running with the code you gave. Still get the same error. Could this be because of an import statement?

Comment: @Michelle Ashwini I tried your snippet. Please remove your imports and use these imports.  import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

Answer (score 0):

Just before and after do the prints:

```
public void testScreenSize(){
System.out.println("Test started");
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(992, 768);
System.out.println("Got dimensions");
driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension);
System.out.println("resizing");
}
```

Check the console and see where it fails, most probably its a compilation issue.